# How to get option selection from table cell with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table header cell with contents like this:

```
<th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
    <select>
        <option value="date" selected="selected">Date</option>
        <option value="number">Number</option>
    </select>
</th>
```

I am trying to get the selected value like this

```
var $selectors = $("#myTable thead tr th").each(function(index)
{
    var cell = $(this).html();
    console.log ("Cell:" + cell.toSource());
    var value = cell.options[cell.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

But I get an error when I try to read the selected value

```
TypeError: cell.selectedIndex is undefined
```

If I dump the cell to the console with cell.toSource() as above it looks like this

```
Cell:(new String("<select><option value=\"\"></option><option value=\"date\" selected=\"selected\">Date</option><option value=\"number\">Number</option></select>"))
```

I have no idea where that 'new String' is coming from, and if it is the source of my problem, or how to get inside of it.  How can I get the selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `selected value` directly using `.val` as you are using `jquery`

```
$(function () {
  $('#myTable thead tr th').each(function () {
      alert($(this).find("select").val());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <table id="myTable"><thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
         <select onchange="change()">
            <option value="date" selected="selected">Date</option>
            <option value="number">Number</option>
         </select>
       </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here is the jquery Code

```
change = function () {
  $('#myTable thead tr th select').each(function () {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
};
```

Here is the working [pen](http://codepen.io/ranavc32/pen/pNBYWW) for you.

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` returns a string. You can use `$(":selected", this)` to get the selected `option` element within `.each()`.

```js
var $selectors = $("#myTable thead tr th")
.each(function(index) {
  var selected = $(":selected", this);
  console.log(selected.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
<th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
    <select>
        <option value="date" selected="selected">Date</option>
        <option value="number">Number</option>
    </select>
</th>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` method to look for the `select` and then `val` method to get the selected value.

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myTable thead tr th").each(function()
 {
   var value = $(this).find('select').val(); // This will get the dropdown's selected value
   alert(value);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable"><thead> <tr>
<th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
    <select>
        <option value="date" selected="selected">Date</option>
        <option value="number">Number</option>
    </select>
</th>
   </tr>
  </thead></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                <select>
                    <option value="date" selected="selected">Date</option>
                    <option value="number">Number</option>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table/>

$('#dataTable thead tr th select [selected="selected"]').val();
```